# Python Plotly: X-Axis Glitches When Attempting to Draw Unified Spike Across Multiple Subplots

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

#### Background

I am currently attempting to draw a unified spike across multiple subplots when hovering. I want to do this to improve the visualization of the x-axis. I am currently following [advice from this thread on GitHub.](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/1677#issuecomment-514661015)

#### My Problem

However, when I try to do it, the x-axis immediately glitches out and shoves all the data to the far right of the chart. Could anyone more familiar with Plotly explain why this is happening? I have included a reproducible piece of code below.

**Note: In order to see the visual bug, you have to uncomment the problematic lines**

#### Reproducible Code

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
from datetime import date

trace1 = go.Scatter(x=[date(2023, 1, 15), date(2023, 2, 15), date(2023, 3, 15), date(2023, 4, 15),
                       date(2023, 5, 15), date(2023, 6, 15), date(2023, 7, 15), date(2023, 8, 15),
                       date(2023, 9, 15), date(2023, 10, 15), date(2023, 11, 15), date(2023, 12, 15)],
                    y=[1000, 2000, 3000, 4000,
                       5000, 6000, 7000, 8000,
                       9000, 10000, 11000, 12000],
                    name='trace1')

trace2 = go.Scatter(x=[date(2023, 1, 15), date(2023, 2, 15), date(2023, 3, 15), date(2023, 4, 15),
                       date(2023, 5, 15), date(2023, 6, 15), date(2023, 7, 15), date(2023, 8, 15),
                       date(2023, 9, 15), date(2023, 10, 15), date(2023, 11, 15), date(2023, 12, 15)],
                    y=[10_000, 20_000, 30_000, 40_000,
                       50_000, 60_000, 70_000, 80_000,
                       90_000, 100_000, 110_000, 120_000],
                    name='trace2')

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1, shared_xaxes=True, vertical_spacing=0.02)

fig.add_trace(trace1, row=1, col=1)
fig.add_trace(trace2, row=2, col=1)

fig.add_annotation(
    xref='x domain',
    yref='y domain',
    x=0,
    y=1,
    text='FIRST ANNOTATION',
    showarrow=False,
    font=dict(size=14, color='blue'),
    row=1, col=1
)

fig.add_annotation(
    xref='x domain',
    yref='y domain',
    x=0,
    y=1,
    text='SECOND ANNOTATION',
    showarrow=False,
    font=dict(size=14, color='red'),
    row=2, col=1
)

# fig.update_traces(xaxis='x')
# fig.update_xaxes(spikemode='across+marker')
# fig.update_shapes(selector=dict(type="line"), xref="x domain")
# fig.update_shapes(selector=dict(type="rect"), xref="x")

fig.update_layout(height=600, width=600, title_text='Example Chart')
fig.show()
```

#### Chart Outputs

| Before Uncommenting | After Uncommenting |
| --- | --- |
| [image] | [image] |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know really why this is happening but it turns out that the x axes (auto)ranges are not computed correctly when we make both traces refer to the same xaxis with `fig.update_traces(xaxis='x')`. To fix that, we need to set the proper range manually. Also instead of `'x'`, we need to refer to `'x2'`, that is, the x axis of the 2nd row, otherwise we loose the date ticks.

Doing the above will make the first annotation disappear, but again we can fix that by setting its `xref` to `'x2 domain'` (instead of 'x'). The weird thing is doing that via `fig.add_annotation()` has no effect (I guess because references to x and/or y are overridden automatically to match the axis id of the subplot corresponding to the specified `row` and `col`), so we have to assign the value manually.

Replacing the commented lines with what follows works correctly :

```py
# The main xaxis is 'x2'
fig.update_traces(xaxis='x2')
fig['layout']['annotations'][0]['xref'] = 'x2 domain'

# Compute xaxes date range 
d0, d1 = min(trace1.x), max(trace1.x)
room = (d1 - d0) * 0.07
d0 -= room
d1 += room

fig.update_xaxes(spikemode='across+marker', type='date', range=[d0, d1])
```

Comment: Could you explain what `fig.update_traces(xaxis='x2')` is even doing? I just copy and pasted that snippet from the linked thread. I don't even understand what its function is.

Comment: This is just to make _both_ traces use `'x2'` as their xaxis. Suplots have their own x/y axes : with 2 rows and 1 column you got xaxis/yaxis for the 1st row and xaxis2/yaxis2 for the 2nd. Those axes are defined in the layout. With `fig.add_trace(trace1, row=1, col=1)`, `xaxis='x'` is the default for trace1, with `fig.add_trace(trace2, row=2, col=1)`, `xaxis='x2'` is the default for trace2. `'x'` refers to `layout.xaxis` and `'x2'` refers to `layout.xaxis2`, etc. Same for the y's. See also the [documentation](https://plotly.com/python/reference/scatter/#scatter-xaxis).